# Video classification using vgg16 and LSTM

Tags: keras

my project is about violence classification using video dataset so i converted all my videos to images every video converted to 7 images .

first i use my vgg16 to extract the features from my images and then train my LSTM on this features , but when i train my LSTM i get bad accuracy and val_accuracy and Strangely, the two values remain constant form many epochs like my accuracy remain 0.5000  for about 50 epoch and the same problem for my validation accuracy .

here is my code if u can figure where is the problem or why the accuracy remain constant and to low .

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Convolution2D, MaxPooling2D, Flatten, Dense, Dropout, GlobalAveragePooling2D
from tensorflow.keras.applications import VGG16
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential 
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D 
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Dropout 
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Flatten, BatchNormalization ,LSTM
import os, shutil
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
import keras 

conv = tf.keras.applications.vgg16.VGG16()

model = Sequential()
```

here i copy my vgg16 to sequential model

```
for layer in conv.layers:
  model.add(layer)
```

here i get rid of all dense and flatten layers making my last layer maxpool with (7,7,512)shape

```
model.pop()
model.pop()
model.pop()
model.pop()

import os, shutil
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

datagen = ImageDataGenerator()
batch_size = 1
img_width, img_height = 224, 224  # Default input size for VGG16
```

this is the function use to extract the features for every pic my arameters is the file path and the number of images in this file .

```
def extract_features(directory, sample_count):
    features = np.zeros(shape=(sample_count, 7, 7, 512))  # Must be equal to the output of the 
    convolutional base
    labels = np.zeros(shape=(sample_count,2))
    # Preprocess data
    generator = datagen.flow_from_directory(directory,
                                            target_size=(img_width,img_height),
                                            batch_size = batch_size,
                                            class_mode='binary')
    # Pass data through convolutional base
    i = 0
    for inputs_batch, labels_batch in generator:
        features_batch = model.predict(inputs_batch)
        features[i * batch_size: (i + 1) * batch_size] = features_batch
        labels[i * batch_size: (i + 1) * batch_size] = labels_batch
        i += 1
        if i * batch_size >= sample_count:
            break
    return features, labels

train_violence="/content/drive/My Drive/images/one/data/train"
train_non="/content/drive/My Drive/images/two/data/train"
valid_violence="/content/drive/My Drive/images/three/data/validation"
valid_non="/content/drive/My Drive/images/four/data/validation"


train_violence_features, train_violence_labels = extract_features(train_violence,119)
train_non_features , train_non_labels = extract_features(train_non,119)
valid_violence_features , valid_violence_labels = extract_features(valid_violence,77) 
valid_non_features , valid_non_labels = extract_features(valid_non,77)
```

now i have my features for violence and non violence features for training and validation so i need to concatenate my 2 arrays for training to make it one array have all violence features then come the non violence features because i found that flow from directory function take the images randomly from the 2 classes but i need it as a sequence so i need every 7 photos come as a sequence so it cant be arranges  randomly from the 2 classes so i used 4 arrays 2 Validation arrays one for violence and one of non violence and the same for the  training and then i concatenate them maintaining the correct sequence for every video .

```
x= np.concatenate((train_violence_features, train_non_features))
y = np.concatenate((valid_violence_features, valid_non_features))
```

now the shape of x is (238, 7, 7, 512) as 228 photo and y for validation is (154, 7, 7, 512)

here i rshape the input for the LSTM to be in shape of(samples , time steps , features) which will be 34 video  for training every video was converted to 7 images so 7 is my time steps and 7*7*512 is the number of features equal to 25088

```
lstm_train_sample = np.reshape(x,(34,7,25088))
lstm_validation_sample = np.reshape(y,(22,7,25088))
```

here i make my labels ->label for every video

```
t_labels = [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
v_labels = [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
t_labels= keras.utils.to_categorical(t_labels, num_classes=2, dtype='float32')
v_labels= keras.utils.to_categorical(v_labels, num_classes=2, dtype='float32')
```

finally my LSTM :

```
lstm = Sequential()
lstm.add(LSTM(200, activation='relu', return_sequences=True, input_shape=(7, 25088)))
lstm.add(LSTM(25, activation='relu'))
lstm.add(Dense(20, activation='relu'))
lstm.add(Dense(10, activation='relu'))
lstm.add(Dense(2))
lstm.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')


lstm.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse',metrics=['accuracy'])

lstm.fit(lstm_train_sample , t_labels , epochs=100 , batch_size=2 , validation_data= 
(lstm_validation_sample,v_labels) , validation_batch_size= 2 )
```

this is an example of the result and i want to know why its like that :

```
Epoch 55/100
17/17 [==============================] - 8s 460ms/step - loss: 0.4490 - accuracy: 0.5000 - val_loss: 1.4238 - val_accuracy: 0.5000
Epoch 56/100
17/17 [==============================] - 8s 464ms/step - loss: 0.4476 - accuracy: 0.5000 - val_loss: 1.4218 - val_accuracy: 0.5000
Epoch 57/100
17/17 [==============================] - 8s 462ms/step - loss: 0.4461 - accuracy: 0.5000 - val_loss: 1.4198 - val_accuracy: 0.5000
Epoch 58/100
17/17 [==============================] - 8s 461ms/step - loss: 0.4447 - accuracy: 0.5000 - val_loss: 1.4176 - val_accuracy: 0.5000
Epoch 59/100
17/17 [==============================] - 8s 457ms/step - loss: 0.4432 - accuracy: 0.5000 - val_loss: 1.4156 - val_accuracy: 0.5000
Epoch 60/100
17/17 [==============================] - 8s 461ms/step - loss: 0.4418 - accuracy: 0.5000 - val_loss: 1.4135 - val_accuracy: 0.5000
Epoch 61/100
17/17 [==============================] - 8s 459ms/step - loss: 0.4403 - accuracy: 0.5000 - val_loss: 1.4114 - val_accuracy: 0.5000
Epoch 62/100
17/17 [==============================] - 8s 458ms/step - loss: 0.4388 - accuracy: 0.5000 - val_loss: 1.4094 - val_accuracy: 0.5000
Epoch 63/100
17/17 [==============================] - 8s 456ms/step - loss: 0.4373 - accuracy: 0.5000 - val_loss: 1.4072 - val_accuracy: 0.5000
Epoch 64/100
17/17 [==============================] - 8s 461ms/step - loss: 0.4358 - accuracy: 0.5000 - val_loss: 1.4051 - val_accuracy: 0.5000
Epoch 65/100
17/17 [==============================] - 8s 467ms/step - loss: 0.4343 - accuracy: 0.5000 - val_loss: 1.4029 - val_accuracy: 0.5000
Epoch 66/100
17/17 [==============================] - 8s 458ms/step - loss: 0.4328 - accuracy: 0.5000 - val_loss: 1.4008 - val_accuracy: 0.5000
Epoch 67/100
17/17 [==============================] - 8s 460ms/step - loss: 0.4313 - accuracy: 0.5000 - val_loss: 1.3987 - val_accuracy: 0.5000
Epoch 68/100
17/17 [==============================] - 8s 461ms/step - loss: 0.4298 - accuracy: 0.5000 - val_loss: 1.3964 - val_accuracy: 0.5000
```

Comment: Did you changing the learning rate ? trying creating an optimizer with lr=2e-5 .

Comment: @AkashBasudevan wow , this reallu helped man i trained it for 100 epoch ant the accuracy was increasing until it became 97% thanks man  but i have still the problem of the validation accuracy for the 100 epoch it was 0.5 so if u have any other advice you will help me so much